# How to resize Django textarea?

Tags: django, django-forms, textarea

Is it possible to resize textarea created by Django?

```
class TextAreaForm(forms.Form):
    input_text_area = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

I want to make it bigger but I don't know how. Is it possible to resize it using Django?

```
  <br>
    {{ text_area_form }}
  <br>
```

I've found only solutions for resizing forms in `Django administration`.

Answer (score 11):

The Django docs describe overriding default fields like so:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from myapp.models import MyModel

class MyForm(ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
          'summary': Textarea(attrs={'rows':80, 'cols':20}),
        }
```

This should be helpful to read through: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)

Comment: Thank you but I can't import ModelForm. And what is MyModel please?

Comment: Sorry, I should've written: `from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea`; edited. As to your other question, `MyModel` is a fill-in for whatever the name of your model is, so you should change it.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. It seems good but still doesn't get why should I use model. I don't use any model in TextAreaForm. It's just form which I recieve a data from and process the text. I have just three models - Level, Language and Freelancer and none of them seems to fit there.

Comment: You should use the model if the text gathered from `TextAreaForm` represents a field in one of your models.

Comment: It's a form where somebody puts the text and then, there is some calculation with this text (number of signs etc.) which is immediately written out. That's all so I don't have to use model.

Comment: You can edit what you wrote originally like this:  `input_text_area = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 80, 'cols': 20}))`